# Codeigniter - jQuery change currency from dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I'd like some help please. I'm having this drop down menu for changing the currency

```
<select id="set-currency" class="form-control">
    <option value="usd">$ USD</option>
    <option value="eur">€ EUR</option>
    <option value="gbp">£ GBP</option>
</select>
```

And this is my script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#set-currency').on('change', function() {
        var selected = $(this).val();
        // alert(selected);    
        $.post({'<?php echo base_url('setcurrency'); ?>', selected });
    });
</script>
```

that sends the new currency setting to this function in MY_Controller

```
public function setcurrency($currency) {
    // reset the currency
    $this->session->set_userdata('currency_code', strtoupper($currency));
}
```

I'm not so good in javascript, so could you help me on how to pass the selected value into the `setcurrency` function in order to change the currency?

Comment: What's happening as of now??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send data using object like this:

```
$.post('<?php echo base_url('setcurrency'); ?>', {currency: selected});
```

And in controller, get the posted variable:

```
public function setcurrency() {
  $currency = $this->input->post('currency');
  // reset the currency
  $this->session->set_userdata('currency_code', strtoupper($currency));
}
```

[Reference:](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/)

Comment: How can I redirect or refresh the page to check if the new currency is set properly ? just use `redirect($go-to-previous-page);` inside my `setcurrency` ???

Comment: For some reason when I moved the `setcurrency` function in another controller that extends MY_Controller worked.. but wouldn't make more sence to have it inside MY_Controller instead ?

Answer (score 0):

Redirect inside ajax function will not work.

```
$.post({'<?php echo base_url('setcurrency'); ?>', {your_post_data},
     function( data ) {
           //redirect here using window.location();
      }
});
```